# Atom Editor not found,Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, atom-editor

I went to check the official repo

```
 curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/AtomEditor/atom/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
Detected operating system as Ubuntu/bionic.
Checking for curl...
Detected curl...
Checking for gpg...
Detected gpg...
Running apt-get update... done.
Installing apt-transport-https... done.
Installing /etc/apt/sources.list.d/AtomEditor_atom.list...done.
Importing packagecloud gpg key... done.
Running apt-get update... done.
```

Next step is to update

```
Err:22 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/ubuntu bionic Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 54.241.144.200 443]
```

I tried Rui's suggestions

```
root@miki:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# mv AtomEditor_atom.list deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main
```

It shows

```
mv: target 'main' is not a directory
```

How to solve this error?

SOLVED
First deleted the file,then

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path for the needed repository does not seems to exist on the remote server as APT is configured.

Replace your file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/AtomEditor_atom.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom-archive.list` **contents** with:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main
```

After that, run `sudo apt update` again.

Note: APT repository configuration line taken from Atom's [github](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/16498) page.